# How to migrate my AngularJS code to Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular

How to migrate my AngularJS code to Angular? Below is the code for the login form.I Want to upgrade this to Angular. Please Help me out. TIA

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {


$scope.submit = function() {
if ($scope.username && $scope.password) {
var user = $scope.username;
var pass = $scope.password;
if (pass == "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
alert("Login Successful");
jQuery(location).attr('href', '')
} else if (user != "manoj@admin.com") {
alert("Invalid username");
} else if (pass != "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
alert("Invalid password");
 }
 }
 }  
 });
```

Below is my HTML code

```
<div class="login-form">
    <div class="login-face" ><div class="text-center"><img src="assets/images/login_face.png" ></div></div>
    <section class="form">
        <form>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </div>

            <div class= "text-center" style="margin-top:50px">
                <input type="submit" id="login" ng-click="submit()" value="Log in"/>
            </div>

        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to add external js file right ????

Comment: add you're file needed to be converted !!

Comment: No, he needs a migration from AngularJS to Angular. Just look at the code he gave.

Comment: yes, i have js file and i want that to be in ts file. How to do that?

Comment: ... Then how come you give us an HTML file ? ...

Comment: rewrite in ts with angular 2+ syntax, if you wanna use angularjs + angular2 in one application, you need hybrid things like router, etc. So, what do you want?

Comment: i'm not able to add my js file here :(

Comment: this is not a free coding service. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez added complete code. Please look at it. Thanks

Comment: I recommend to use 
Pranay Rana anwser's

Answer (score 0):

For detail go here : [External JavaScript dependencies in Typescript and Angular 2](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/12/External-JavaScript-dependencies-in-Typescript-and-Angular-2#Importinganexternallibrary)

For eample to user jquery do as below

1. install jquery : `npm install jquery --save`
2. import jquery whree you want to use : import * as $ from 'jquery';

this will do for you.or still face issue do like

```
declare var $:any;
```

and then use it.

---

for external js file , first add this file to you angular project, add it in your externalJS(create new folder if you dont have it) folder than rerfer it in you index.html

```
<script src="./externalJS/test.js"></script>
```

add this in you application.compnent.ts like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var test: any;//refers you js file 

  f(){
    new test();
  }
}
```

js file

```
function test(){
    alert('call me!!')
}
```

if you are using Angular-Cli based angular project than just include js file in your angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],//add your javascript file here 
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try and get back to you :)

Comment: @ManojMogalla - updated my answer ..you cna also go to link i suggested ..if works for you please do upvote /accept answer

Comment: Hello, can you please check the below code of my js file. $scope can be used in Angular?

Comment: @ManojMogalla -do include like as below  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>